# iTerm2 - restore Command History on restart?

Tags: iterm2

I am using iTerm2 on OSX (13.4).  I would like **Command History** restored when I start iTerm2.

- Shell Integration is active, https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html
- Toolbelt / Command History and Toolbelt / Show Toolbelt are open (see image)

When I quit iTerm2 and re-open the Command History is blank.

I am sure I am missing something very simple here?

[image]